# how to custom design the way numbers are displayed

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, storyboard

I am developing a game in Swift that I want  to display the score in LED type of format.
The way I am thinking to do that is to have 6 UIImageView in the story board next to each other for the score. and when the score is changed, convert the score which is in Integer to String, and then parse each character in that string and set the background of each imageview to a correct image which correspond to the correct LED image for that digit. 
Am I thinking in a right way or there is an easier approach?

Comment: have you tried using a custom font?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just use [one of all these LED fonts](http://www.1001fonts.com/led-fonts.html), embed it in the App and use a standard `UILabel` to render the scores.